# Correct way to avoid element jumping to bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

So currently I run some Javascript on page load that moves a website footer div to the bottom of the page if the page content is shorter than the total page height.

It looks like this:

```
if (window.addEventListener) { // Mozilla, Netscape, Firefox
    window.addEventListener('load', windowLoad, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
    window.attachEvent('onload', windowLoad);
}

function windowLoad(event) {
    //Set min-height to viewport height
    if (/*Page elements height*/ < $(window).height()) {
        $(".content").css('min-height', $(window).height() - /*Page elements height*/;
    }
}
```

The issue is that on even a reasonably fast connection there's a noticable jump where the footer is initially just below the content, and then jumps to the bottom of the page. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: You might want to Google 'css sticky footer' as I think that's what you're after and there are much cleaner solutions out there (here's an example that has excellent compatibility: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/browser-list.html). If you still want to use JS then you could set the footer's opacity to zero then fade it in after the min-height is set for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jQuery already, you can use that to bind the events. That way you don't need different code for different browsers.

You can also use the `ready` event instead of the `load` event, which happens earlier in the page load process. The `ready` event is the cross-browser version on the `DOMContentLoaded` event, where jQuery emulates the event for browsers that doesn't support it (i.e. IE).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Set min-height to viewport height
  if (/*Page elements height*/ < $(window).height()) {
    $(".content").css('min-height', $(window).height() - /*Page elements height*/;
  }
});
```